# Correct way to use goto statement to transfer control to a label after go

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example. The following code fails because the 'ReturnControl' label is not recognized as it is after the go statement. But I need the configuration code for the query on the top as it gets modified repeatedly and it is easier to access instead of skimming through the whole query and finding the lines that need to be changed.

I am not limited to using `goto`. I am open to any other suggestions or methods that would allow keeping configuration logic on top of the query.

```
GOTO BatchSetup;

ReturnControl:
/*
    Set Parameters here.
    Configuration code that gets modified repeatedly
*/
Insert ##Parameters VALUES ('SomeParam', 'paramValue')
EXEC #CreateJob 'Job1'
EXEC #CreateJob 'Job2'

EXEC #ExecuteJob 'Job1'
EXEC #ExecuteJob 'Job2'

GOTO ENDBatch;

BatchSetup:
CREATE TABLE ##Jobs
(
    ID  INT IDENTITY,
    JobName NVARCHAR(100),
);

CREATE TABLE ##Parameters
(
    ParamName NVARCHAR(100),
    ParamValue NVARCHAR(100),
);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC #CreateJob
    @JobName    NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT ##Jobs (JobName) VALUES (@JobName);
END
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC #ExecuteJob
    @JobName    NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Param NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT ParamValue FROM ##Parameters WHERE ParamName = 'SomeParam');
    /*
        Code to execute Job
    */
END
GO

GOTO ReturnControl;

ENDBatch:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Jobs;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Parameters;
DROP PROC IF EXISTS #CreateJob;
DROP PROC IF EXISTS #ExecuteJob;
```

Edit:
I have restructured the query based on suggestions that somewhat did the job.

```
/*
    Setup: Create temp stored procedures and temp tables. Access value using SESSION_CONTEXT
/*
    Set Parameters here.
    Configuration code that gets modified repeatedly
*/
EXEC sp_set_session_context @Key = 'key1', @Value = 'value1';
EXEC sp_set_session_context @Key = 'key2', @Value = 'value2;


EXEC Job1
EXEC Job2
EXEC Cleanup
```

Comment: `GOTO` can not span batches

Comment: The actual batches that SQL Server client tools deal with are *delimited* by `GO`. The client tools send each batch *individually* to the server for it to compile and execute them. It cannot execute a batch containing branches to labels not even yet submitted to it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but maybe you could use `SESSION_CONTEXT` to set the values at the top of the script and have your later code read those values rather than try elaborate flow of control routing. Or run the whole thing in SQL cmd mode and use sqlcmd `setvar` to assign values that will get interpolated in later

Comment: Do you even need the `GO` batch separator? But as Martin said, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why have temp stored procedures?

Comment: I see what I was trying isn't really possible. I have a .SQL query file that a developer is supposed to run when setting up databases but it has specific parameters that can be changed as per requirement.

What I trying to do is have a section in a query that is separate from the rest of the file (like on top of the file) where parameters can be set. So the developer does not have to skim through the whole file looking for the values to change and does not have to look through all that complexity.

@MartinSmith , using SESSION_CONTEXT somewhat did that job, as it reduces certain complexity

Comment: @DaleK, Yes. I do need the go batch separator, As I am adding temporary stored procedures to avoid code duplication. Stored procedure creation must be followed by 'Go'.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I have restructured the query as per your suggestion which can be seen in the edit. Please add the `SESSION_CONTEXT` suggestion so that I can accept it as a solution. Thanks.